# How can I send text that is formatted for the console to a text file in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to mirror what I write to console to a text file.  Here's the code I've written, but it isn't creating the txt file.  Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
-(NSString *) display
{
    NSLog (@" \n ");
    NSLog (@"|========== Contents of: %@ =============|", listName);
    NSLog (@"|__________________________________________________|");
    NSLog (@"|    | Song Title |    |         | Artist |        |");
    NSLog (@"|    ==============    |         ==========        |");
    NSLog (@"|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|");

    for ( SongRecord *theRecord in list )
        NSLog (@"|  %-20s|  %-24s |", [theRecord.songname UTF8String],
           [theRecord.artist UTF8String]);

    NSLog (@"====================================================");

    return listing;
}


-(void) saveToFile
{
     NSString* fileName = @"Mysongs.txt";
     NSString* fullPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];



     [[self display] writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding    error:nil];

     NSLog (@"The file has been written");

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify `-display` so that it builds a string that you can actually return for use in `-saveToFile`. At the same time, you can send it to console, as you wish:

```
- (NSString *)display
{
    NSMutableString *listing = [NSMutableString string];

    [listing appendString:@"\n"];
    [listing appendFormat:@"|========== Contents of: %@ =============|\n", listName];
    [listing appendString:@"|__________________________________________________|\n"];
    [listing appendString:@"|    | Song Title |    |         | Artist |        |\n"];
    [listing appendString:@"|    ==============    |         ==========        |\n"];
    [listing appendString:@"|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|\n"];

    for (SongRecord *theRecord in list)
    {
        [listing appendFormat:@"|  %-20s|  %-24s |\n", [theRecord.songname UTF8String], [theRecord.artist UTF8String]];
    }

    [listing appendString:@"====================================================\n"];

    NSLog(@"%@", listing);

    // Do this to return an immutable string, as your method signature says it will.
    return [NSString stringWithString:listing];
}
```

Comment: @trudyscousin Thanks for the reply.  What you said makes sense, but my text file still isn't being created.  I believe my saveToFile method is correct, could the problem lie in there?

Comment: trudyscousin, is it necessary to strictly return NSString's? In my code, I tend not to. Why is not acceptable to return a descendant subclass for a method? Is there a reason that I cannot think of?

Comment: @DavidPosey Please forgive the long delay; I had turned in for the night. I just fed some data to your code and tried it out; it works just fine. One thing you don't describe in your examples is the variable `path`; that's important in determining where your file is located, so be sure to check that.

Comment: @BenjaminMayo As with David, please forgive the long wait. Certainly you can return a NSMutableString; it "is a" subclass of NSString and you can return it as such. It's bad form, though. Remember that references to objects in Cocoa are often shared; a reference held by one object (that expects it to be immutable, and yet it isn't) could be changed by another object unexpectedly, compromising the first object's expectations of its value (and immutability).

Comment: @trudyscousin I have a seperate method to set my directory for "path".  Here is my code:-(void) setCurrentDirectory
{

     NSString *path;
     NSFileManager *fm;
     
     fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     
     [fm changeCurrentDirectoryPath: @"/Users/twidget60/"];
     
     path = [fm currentDirectoryPath];
    
     NSLog (@"Current Directory path is %@", path);
    

}

Comment: @trudyscousin I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get the program to make the text file.  could it be a permissions problem?  If so, what is the best way to fix that?  As before, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @trudyscousin : Namaste :) So you know about India?

Comment: @DavidPosey I see what you're trying to do, to set the current directory. That's all very good for the shell, but`-writeToFile:atomically:encoding:' knows nothing of that. You must provide the entire path to the method.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I know just a little, that which my colleagues teach me. :)

Comment: @trudyscousin can i u in gmail :)

Comment: so give me you id or add me in vaidya.anoop

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the help.  It ended up being a problem with how I was defining my path.  I changed to NSHomeDirectory and it works like a charm.  Thanks again, especially @trudyscousin.